# PocketBase "must not be in list" error when creating new collection

Tags: flutter, pocketbase

I am trying to create a new "Feedback" collection in my PocketBase database but I am getting an error when trying to add an `id` field.

Each feedback item should be connected to a user via the user's `id` so I am using a `Relation` field type.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a simple mistake. New collections automatically come with the following fields:

- id
- created
- updated

The "must not be in list" error means you need to name the field something else. In my case I just changed it to `user_id`.

Comment: You should mark this as the answer